# C programming - Open file with variable name

Tags: c, fopen

I have a lot of folders, and in each folder there are a lot of files, but the sequence of folders and files starts from 0 till 100 etc.. I'm trying to open each file using a for loop to read what's in this file, but I'm always getting an error that the file pointer is NULL. Please help

```
for(int folder=0; folder<100; folder++) {

    if(flag == 1)
        break;

    for(int file=fileNumber; file<=fileNumber; file++) {       
        char address[100] = {'\0'};
        sprintf(address,"/Volumes/Partition 2/data structure/tags/%d/%d.txt",folder,fileNumber);
        files=fopen(address,"r");
        if(files == NULL) {

            printf("Error opening the file!\n");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Try adding `printf(address)` to the error handler.  Then run it and do `ls <whatever-got-printed>`

Comment: `file=fileNumber; file<=fileNumber` <-- typo?

Comment: AShelly I'm getting no such directory when I use ls although the directory is there. :/
I'm on Mac OSX

Comment: Michael the type is int

Comment: The type isn't the issue, the problem is that you've written the loop to only run once.

Comment: when you use `ls`, don't forget to put the name in quotes because of the space in the pathname.

Comment: Paul actually the issue here is that I can't get into the destination, it's not opening the file at all

Comment: To clarify, shouldn't `file` start at 0, not at `fileNumber`?

Comment: @AliZahr, AShelly mentioned above' Then run it and do ls <whatever-got-printed>'; to which you replied:'I'm getting no such directory when I use ls although the directory is there'.  If `ls` cannot find the directory, you should probably determine why that is.  Make sure `ls` can access the directories and files involved, and you will most likely discover the problem with the question code.

Comment: Try calling `perror()` after `fopen()` fails to find out exactly why it's failing. My bet is that you're not getting the filenames right, or you don't have the correct permissions, or something like that. Try running it to reference just files of form `%d.txt` in the current directory and see if that works, to at least rule out anything else funny.

Comment: In addition to the file starting from 0, not fileNumber, you should use 'file' in the sprintf, not fileNumber.

Comment: @GwynEvans: Turns out that's the answer, you should add it as one, well spotted.

Comment: I'd suggest you to print the filenames when `fopen` fails: `printf("Error opening the file '%s'!\n", address);` and verify you're trying to open proper files... Additionally IF/WHEN you succeed, don't forget to close the file: `if(files==NULL) { print_error;} else { use_the_file; fclose(files); }` – otherwise you're likely to run out of system max number of opened files.

Answer (score 0):

Gwyn Evans has your answer pegged in the comments, so give him the credit if he provides an answer, but you have two issues:

- You're starting your second loop from `fileNumber`, instead of from `0`; and
- You are not writing the correct filename into `address`, since you're using `fileNumber` when you should be using `file`.

The following modification of your algorithm should work for you, in the absence of any problems in the rest of the absolute path you're using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int fileNumber = 4;

    for (int folder = 0; folder < 2; folder++) {
        for (int file = 0; file < fileNumber; file++) {
            char address[100] = {'\0'};

            sprintf(address, "%d/%d.txt", folder, file);
            printf("Trying to open file %s...\n", address);

            FILE * files = fopen(address, "r");
            if (files == NULL) {
                perror("Couldn't open file");
            } else {
                printf("Successfully opened file %s\n", address);
                fclose(files);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/fop$ ls
0       1       fopen   fopen.c
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/fop$ ls 0
0.txt 1.txt 3.txt
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/fop$ ls 1
0.txt 1.txt 3.txt
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/fop$ ./fopen
Trying to open file 0/0.txt...
Successfully opened file 0/0.txt
Trying to open file 0/1.txt...
Successfully opened file 0/1.txt
Trying to open file 0/2.txt...
Couldn't open file: No such file or directory
Trying to open file 0/3.txt...
Successfully opened file 0/3.txt
Trying to open file 1/0.txt...
Successfully opened file 1/0.txt
Trying to open file 1/1.txt...
Successfully opened file 1/1.txt
Trying to open file 1/2.txt...
Couldn't open file: No such file or directory
Trying to open file 1/3.txt...
Successfully opened file 1/3.txt
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch/fop$
```

Moral of this story: if things aren't working, trying `printf()`ing `address` to check what files you're *actually* trying to open.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, but I'm happy for this to be marked as the answer as it's a good answer that the OP can use, whereas my comment wasn't a decent answer in itself, just pointing them in the right direction!